# How to set background image on Flask Templates?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

My background-image works only for this template that has @app.route('/').

```
 <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('static/img/home.jpg')">
```

This works perfectly fine when:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('post.html')
```

Everything works. I get this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2016 21:07:11] "GET /static/img/home.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304
```

But when I use same template with:

```
@app.route('/post/')
def post():
     return render_template('post.html')
```

I get this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2016 21:15:23] "GET /post/static/img/home.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

And background-image is blank.

Comment: Give site-relative link: `url(/static/...)` and not document relative

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[This is a simple problem can solved by Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/static/)

Anyway, you should use something like this in your template:

```
background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='img/home.jpg') }})
```

but if you don't want to use Flask methods use :

```
url('/static/img/home.jpg')
```

or use another web server instead of flask default web server for your files like Apache and access via `http://yoursite/static/img/home.jpg`

Comment: I tried this method, it seems that it only works when the directory's name is "static". Is that right?

Comment: The first method if you put your background image in html file. the second method if you put your background-image in css.

Answer (score 6):

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document - [w3 CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url)

This means that you need to change your `url()` a bit, to include the leading `/`.

```
"background-image: url('/static/img/home.jpg')"
```

Answer (score 1):

4 years, 7 months too late, but anyways just in case someone needs help..

I found flask recognized my .jpg image was located in 'static', so adding 'static' like so "background-image: url('/static/img/home.jpg')", is adding an "extra" static.
What worked for me, using the skeleton approach,

background-image: url('home.jpg');

Simple and bare, like a skeleton.