# Flask Boostrap background image options

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I am new to flask. I want to display a background image in the jumbotron using Bootstrap in Flask in the home.html page. However, I am not able to resize it. Also, my text "Tomvar" and other texts is coming below the image and not over it. The details of home.html and jumboron.css. is given below

My **home.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<main role="main">

  <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

   <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='image/home_bg.png')}}" class="image1"/>

      <h1 class="display-3">TomVar</h1>
      <p>A database for variations in Tomato</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus  </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

  </div> <!-- /container -->

</main>
{% endblock %}

<footer class="container">
  <p>&copy; Company 2017-2018</p>
</footer>
```

My **jumbotron.css** which is in my static/css folder:

```
body {

    padding-top: 3.5rem;
}
.image1 {

 opacity: 0.5;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `background-size: cover` cover on an `<img>`. Its only for background images.

If you want to insert an actual `<img>` Instead use `object-fit: cover`

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.jumbotron-content {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" class="jumbotron-image" />

    <div class="jumbotron-content">
      <h1 class="display-3">TomVar</h1>
      <p>A database for variations in Tomato</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Conversely, you could just add an inline style for a background image (using flask) on your `.jumbotron`

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron-content {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/800/500)">

    <div class="jumbotron-content">
      <h1 class="display-3">TomVar</h1>
      <p>A database for variations in Tomato</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, actually, the text over the jumbotron is not seen anymore due to the image. How do I set it as a background image in the flask-way ?

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly. But if I would like to use url_for, how should I change the path? I am using as of now: `<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='image/home_bg.png')}})">`  Its throwing an error..any clue ? Thanks

Comment: Where does the error come form and what does it say?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579810/5385381 Or the answer below it?